# SharePoint 2013 - how do you programmatically set the search results url?

Tags: c#, search, settings, sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint 2013 I want to programmatically set the search results url. There doesn't appear to be a setting at the root web or site level that appears to allow for this assignment. With a powershell dictionary dump `$mySite.RootWeb.AllProperties`, I see that there are some properties at the root web that look like the likely suspects `SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL_SITE`, `SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL_WEB`, `SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL`; however, I'm left to guess what these values refer too though. What is the proper way to programmatically set the search results url in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to this is to set the `SRCH_SB_SET_SITE` root web property with a JSON string as follows:

```
{"Inherit":false,"ResultsPageAddress":"~sitecollection/Pages/SearchResults.aspx","ShowNavigation":false}
```

C# code:

```
rootWeb.AllProperties["SRCH_SB_SET_SITE"] = "{\"Inherit\":false,\"ResultsPageAddress\":\"~sitecollection/Pages/SearchResults.aspx\",\"ShowNavigation\":false}";
rootWeb.Update();
```